# In orienteering/navigation, what is an attack point?

Tags: navigation, terminology, orienteering

Some features in orienteering or navigation are called attack points. What exactly does this refer to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To put it really simply, an **attack point is something that you can aim towards, that is far more obvious and easy to navigate to than your actual destination.**

For examples consider navigating to a lava tube cave in a forest with bluffs around. While the cave won't be visible until you are really close to it, the bluffs will stick out above the trees and you can use them to aim in addition to using a map and compass.

[image]

Another good example would be heading towards a glacier lake at the bottom of a mountain to camp, the mountain peak will be visible for quite a ways farther, especially when navigating through dense terrain.

[image]